# Enabling SSL in HDI Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, ssl-certificate, azure-hdinsight, ambari

I'm using Azure HDInsight Hadoop cluster - Cluster type, HDI Ver:Hadoop 2.7 (HDI 3.6). This is not Kerberised cluster as ESP is not enabled. Now I need to enable SSL on this hadoop cluster. How can i ensure that SSL is enabled in hadoop cluster? I could see hadoop.ssl.enabled property as false in core-default.xml file.

Now how to enable SSL on this hadoop cluster.

Appreciate your he
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Azure HDInsight requires **Enterprise security package** to enable SSL/TLS protocols.

> Enabling SSL/TLS for AAD DS?

HDInsight requires that you enable LDAPS for AAD DS. If you have a public domain configure as your primary in Azure AD then you can obtain a public certificate from public CA such as Symantec or DigiTrust. However, if your primary is using the default Microsoft provided domain .onmicrosoft.com, then since you don’t own onmicrosoft.com you will need to use a self-signed certificate and request an exception by raising a support case with Microsoft.

Next an SSL certificate needs to be uploaded in PFX format with the private key (you will also need the password) via the Azure portal and enable Secure LDAP.

Ensure that “Allow secure LDAP access over the internet” is (which is the default).

Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) is used to read from and write to Azure Active Directory. You can make LDAP traffic confidential and secure by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) or Transport Layer Security (TLS) technology. You can enable LDAP over SSL (LDAPS) by installing a properly formatted certificate.

For more information about secure LDAP, see [Configure LDAPS for an Azure AD DS managed domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-configure-ldaps).

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-configure-ldaps

Hope this helps.